# What is the automorphism group of affine space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am writing my undergraduate thesis about theorem I.7.7 from Hartshorne, which generalizes Bézout's theorem to intersections in arbitrarily high-dimensional projective space. The first chapter is a quick presentation of affine varieties. At the end of this chapter, I give a couple of examples where Bézout's theorem fails in affine space.

My goal is to demonstrate that I have actually understood *something*, rather than just recite theorems from Hartshorne and Atiyah-Macdonald. So I want to give a heuristic justification for *why* we should expect Bézout's theorem to fail in affine space. The basic idea is that the degree of an affine variety $V \subset \mathbb A^n$, which we should really think of as an embedding $\iota : V \to \mathbb A^n$, is not a well-defined geometric (i.e., coordinate-free) property of $V$ in the first place. For example, the map $\varphi : \mathbb A^2 \to \mathbb A^2$ given by $\varphi(x,y) = (x, y + x^2)$ sends the $x$ axis to the parabola $y = x^2$.

I don't really intend to prove any proofs for the above argument, which is heuristic anyway. However, I would like to know what the automorphism group of $\mathbb A^n$ is, so that I can mention that it contains weird stuff that destroys any hope that Bézout's theorem should hold.

What is the automorphism group of affine space?

Comment: Your objection to degree depending on embedding also holds in projective space. For example, an elliptic curve can be embedding in $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a degree $n+1$ curve for any $n\geq 2$. So I'm not sure this will be an effective heuristic.

Comment: @DKS you're forgetting translations. OP: the reason the result doesn't hold is that there are obvious counterexamples: any parallel hyperplanes don't intersect. The thing that makes projective space nice for this is that if you expect two varieties to intersect based on their codimensions, they actually intersect (this is in the intersections in projective space section of Hartshorne).

Comment: @DKS: There is nothing wrong with depending on the chosen embedding. That is why I said that “a variety $V \subset \mathbb A^n$ should really be thought of as an embedding $\iota : V \to \mathbb A^n$”.

Comment: @KReiser: Yes, that is the second part of theorem I.7.2. But I think I don't need to prove it. It can be obtained en passant from theorem I.7.7. (In fact, I am going even further: I don't prove anything from Hartshorne as Hartshorne does it. Instead, I prove almost everything from chapter 11 in Atiyah purely algebraically, and then reinterpret it geometrically in an almost zero-effort manner.)

Comment: I don't know much about this but my understanding is that there is quite a lot that is not known about the automorphisms of affine space.  In particular, one famous open question is the [Jacobian conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture).

Comment: @pyon the point is that the automorphism group of affine space doesn't matter for showing that intersections don't behave like you would want them to behave and you're barking up the wrong tree for this. Go talk to your advisor and they'll help you get straightened out.

Comment: @KReiser $Aut(k(x,y)/k)$ is a complicated group but it is generated by a few elementary transformations, is it the same with $Aut(k[x,y]/k)$ and $Aut(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/k)$ ?

Comment: @reuns my comment was correct but incomplete: certainly translations were missing, but there's a lot more that's missing too. For instance, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+x^n)$ is an automorphism which I did not describe. As Eric Wofsey states, there's a lot we don't know about it. For instance, I do not know the answer to your question.

Comment: @reuns The automorphism group of $k[x,y]$ is the amalgamated product of the `elementary' ones and affine maps (which is just translation coupled with $GL_2$). For more than 2 variables, these are not known.